# How to find unit-sample response

Tags: dsp

I have found:
$$Y = (X + Y)R^3$$
then
$$\frac{Y}{X} = \frac{R^3}{1-R^3}$$
then
$$\frac{Y}{X} = \frac{1}{(z-1)(z-e^{j2\pi/3})(z-e^{-j2\pi/3})}$$
then I have three poles: $$1, e^{j2\pi/3}, e^{-j2\pi/3}$$
but from now, How can I find y[n] ?

Slide source: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-003-signals-and-systems-fall-2011/resources/mit6_003f11_lec03/

[image]